# Sending mail using python is getting an error

Tags: python, email, smtp

I'm using python and SMTP to send mail

I'm Getting Error in it

My code is

```
import smtplib

smtp_server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
smtp_server.ehlo()
smtp_server.starttls()
smtp_server.login('something@gmail.com', '587')

smtp_server.sendmail('pybitesblog@gmail.com', 'recipient@gmail.com', 'Subject: Happy Australia Day!\nHi Everyone! Happy  Day! Cheers, Julian')

smtp_server.quit()
print('Email sent successfully')
```

and
 Errors are

```
error: [Error 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

error: [error 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably firewall is blocking the connection, please check your settings.

Comment: Please run in terminal `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587`  and add the output here.

Comment: I removed setting from firewall and now it works.. Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your firewall blocks the connection. once remove the script would work.